# Python: Comparing string variable against multiple sub-strings

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to learn python from Perl. In Perl, if I want to compare a string against multiple sub-strings, I would use the following:

```
sub matchCity {
    my $cityName = shift;
    print "$cityName is a valid city name\n" if ($cityName =~ /kyo|par|omba/);
}

matchCity('tokyo'); # tokyo is a valid city name
matchCity('paris'); # paris is a valid city name
matchCity('bombay'); # bombay is a valid city name
matchCity('chicago'); # Doesn't print anything
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: WHAT'S WRONG WITH CHICAGO!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

def matchCity(city_name):
    if re.search('kyo|par|omba', city_name):
        print "{} is a valid city name".format(city_name)

matchCity('tokyo') # tokyo is a valid city name
matchCity('paris') # paris is a valid city name
matchCity('bombay') # bombay is a valid city name
matchCity('chicago') # Doesn't print anything
```

Comment: Don't all of them return `None`?

Comment: The function returns `None`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  In the comments you added, you annotate that when `'chicago'` is passed, it returns `undef`.  I was saying that a) shouldn't that be `None`, and b) since all of them return `None`, the return value can't be checked to see if the city matches or not (since I assume that's why it was mentioned that it returns `undef`).

Comment: Seth is right here: With Perl, a subroutine returns the value of the last calculation unless there is an explicit return value. Python returns `None` unless there is an explicit return value.

Comment: Ah, ok, I copied those lines verbatim from the question

Comment: @SethMMorton, Neither the match nor the sub return undef in the Perl code. And the Perl sub's return value is not useful. I've fixed the OP, so I fixed gnibbler's comment too.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need regex for this:

```
>>> def matchCity(s):
...     if any(r in s for r in ('kyo','par','omba')):
...         print s, 'is a valid city name'
... 
>>> matchCity('tokyo')
tokyo is a valid city name
>>> matchCity('paris')
paris is a valid city name
>>> matchCity('bombay')
bombay is a valid city name
>>> matchCity('chicago')  # doesn't print anything
>>>
```

Comment: Don't all of them return `None`?

Comment: if i replace the print with a simple statement (i used `x=1`) to get valid timings, this appears to be about twice fast as the re method (1.15 uS vs. 2.01uS on my machine).

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I'm not at all surprised. The re approach does a lot of work behind the scenes (parsing the regular expression etc.).

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions:

```
import re
city = re.compile('kyo|par|omba', re.I)
matchCity = lambda x: city.search(x)
```

And you can use `matchCity("example_city")` as condition:

```
if matchCity("tokyo"):   print "Valid city!" # Valid city!
if matchCity("paris"):   print "Valid city!" # Valid city!
if matchCity("bombay"):  print "Valid city!" # Valid city!
if matchCity("chicago"): print "Valid city!" #
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has regular expressions.  So you could do this:

```
import re

city_names = re.compile(r'kyo|par|omba')

def match_city(city_name):
    if city_names.search(city_name):
        print city_name, "is a valid city name"
```

Normally I would tell you to avoid regular expressions if you can.  But matching one of multiple sub-strings is actually a case where they likely perform better than a loop. This is especially true as the number of sub-strings grows.

Comment: According to the comments on @arshajii's post, `re` is slower than string methods even in this case.

Comment: but he might be right... the test i did includes the compile of the regex, and if you have more substrings to check, the timing advantage might shift. will try it later.